# how to set up a .Mac/MobileMe account in Evolution?

Tags: evolution, email, calendar, apple

What settings are necessary for setting up a .Mac account? At the VERY least for mail but would like calendars as well if its even a possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mail is simple enough. You just need to set up an account in Evo to use IMAP:

```
The settings for MobileMe IMAP should be as follows:

Incoming server: mail.me.com or mail.mac.com (doesn't seem to matter which one you use).
SSL: On
Incoming server port: 993

Outgoing server: smtp.me.com
SSL: On
Authentication: Password
Outgoing server port: 587
```

Yoinked from here: http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/658662-mobileme-imap-settings/

I don't know how to sync calendars though. You might need to proxy it through something else that can sync to it and then connect evo to that (Can google calendar do that?)